# Difference between UIComponent's isInView() and isRendered()

Tags: jsf

What is the difference between the methods [isInView()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#isInView%28%29) and [isRendered()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#isRendered%28%29) from the UIComponent class?

I couldn't figure out by reading the description provided in the api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only of interest if you're dynamically creating/manipulating the JSF component tree. It indicates whether the component instance in question is member of the JSF component tree (the "view").

E.g., assuming that `someParentComponent` is already present in the view (as child of `UIViewRoot`):

```
UIComponent newComponent = new SomeComponent();
System.out.println(newComponent.isInView()); // false
someParentComponent.getChildren().add(newComponent);
System.out.println(newComponent.isInView()); // true
someParentComponent.getChildren().remove(newComponent);
System.out.println(newComponent.isInView()); // false
```

Makes sense?

You must already know what the `rendered` attribute stands for (during render response phase, if `true` (and in view), then generate HTML, otherwise if `false`, then don't generate HTML).

Comment: It totally makes sense. So it is possible that, for the same component, I get `true` as a return for `isInView()` and `false` for `isRendered()`?